# Oracle 11g - Update bulk with index vs without

Tags: performance, oracle, parallel-processing, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a table containing 50M records and I have to update almost all of it. I want to use parallel update on the table. Which will be faster, having indexes on the table or without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to update almost all of the table, then I suspect the access method used will be a full table scan - which means the indexes won't be used to speed up the queries.

Therefore, the only impact that indexes may have will be the extra work required to maintain them for the update - so the more indexes, the slower your update will be.